# Memorizing code, pros how do you do it

Tags: unix

I apologize that this isn't a technical question, but as a programming student, I find it difficult at times to remember various arguments (especially in BASH scripting), so my question to the pros is, do you use references and "cheat sheets" or is it all from memory?

Answer (score 5):

We don't memorise as in memorising the multiplication table. We memorise as in playing a musical instrument: kept using it.

Comment: Just right! Or to do a more geeky comparison, as in touch-typing. Do you look at the keyboard when typing or is it all from memory?

Answer (score 4):

We memorize only one command, `man` and bookmark only one URL, The [Portable Operating System Interface (POSIX)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) which provides the cheat sheets for shell and kernel programming alike. We learn C only from one book, *Kernighan, Ritchie: The C Programming Language* and Unix/Network programming only with W.Richard Stevens' books.

Everything else is expendable :-)

Comment: hi just read your comment, I got myself a copy of the Unix network programming by richard stevens, just wondering if this is the right book, this seems to be the oldest of the network programming books by stevens, any advice would be appreciated or should I opt for a newer book?http://www.amazon.com/UNIX-Network-Programming-Richard-Stevens/dp/0139498761/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1389637379&sr=8-2&keywords=Unix+network+programming

Comment: @tesseract Stevens' books are timeless. Network programming basically hasn't changed. Sockets, ioctls, datagrams, protocols -- it's programmed the same. One thing I can think of that might be missing is the in-depth handling of security related aspects of the transport layer. Nobody will ever question your judgement with a Stevens book. It even appears as a chick-magnet in the Wayne's World movie :-)

Comment: thanks for the reply!!. I feel reassured hearing it from an experienced Machine :). I am just getting started in some serious network programming, need to find a way into the matrix:), and figure stuff out!. Also Own the K&R book on C, absolutely epic books. I Had to youtube that scene in Wayne's World epic!!feel better already :)

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess there is no real way to memorize things, you need to really have an understanding of the commands. To be honest a lot of people still may need to look in the "man" for particular commands to find all their options. The first step is feeling comfortable with bash and the commands and having a general appreciation of how bash commands generally work.

Then there is good old fashioned repeated use which will get you more familiar with the commands and then it will become second nature. So I guess the answer is to get a general appreciation and keep learning and applying what you learn on a regular basis.

I personally have a cheat sheet of commands that i use on my setup.

Comment: Thanks! I also have a clipboard with various cheatsheets and examples of people's source code to use as examples

Answer (score 0):

The more you code the less you will need to look something up. Google is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, try focus on remembering concepts and not variables or function names.

Secondly, using cheatsheets and references is a good choice for beginner, you can even print it and put nearby.

Comment: That what I do now, which is really helpful, i mean there are some arguments that I use so much I don't need it such as -p or -P for port and -r for recursive.